# Testing a docker instance with beaker

Tags: puppet, docker

I have a suite of Beaker tests running against a docker host.

I dont know the intricacies of how docker handles swap files, but it seems that it doesn't like it.

The Puppet code looks like this:

```
exec { 'Create swap file':
  command => "/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=${swapfile} bs=1M count=${swapfilesize_mb}",
  creates => $swapfile,
}
exec { 'Attach swap file':
  command => "/sbin/mkswap ${swapfile} && /sbin/swapon ${swapfile}",
  require => Exec['Create swap file'],
  unless  => "/sbin/swapon -s | grep ${swapfile}",
}
if $add_mount {
  mount { 'swap':
    ensure  => present,
    fstype  => swap,
    device  => $swapfile,
    dump    => 0,
    pass    => 0,
    require => Exec['Attach swap file'],
  }
}
```

And the error message is as follows:

```
Info: Loading facts
Notice: Compiled catalog for centos-6-x64 in environment production in 0.22 seconds
Info: Applying configuration version '1411345072'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Swap_file/Exec[Create swap file]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: /Stage[main]/Swap_file/Exec[Attach swap file]/returns: mkswap: /tmp/swapfile: warning: don't erase bootbits sectors
Notice: /Stage[main]/Swap_file/Exec[Attach swap file]/returns:         on whole disk. Use -f to force.
Notice: /Stage[main]/Swap_file/Exec[Attach swap file]/returns: Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 5116 KiB
Notice: /Stage[main]/Swap_file/Exec[Attach swap file]/returns: no label, UUID=ceb75f7d-ae8b-4781-bd1b-4123bec9bcf1
Notice: /Stage[main]/Swap_file/Exec[Attach swap file]/returns: swapon: /tmp/swapfile: swapon failed: Input/output error
Error: /sbin/mkswap /tmp/swapfile && /sbin/swapon /tmp/swapfile returned 255 instead of one of [0]
Error: /Stage[main]/Swap_file/Exec[Attach swap file]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: /sbin/mkswap /tmp/swapfile && /sbin/swapon /tmp/swapfile returned 255 instead of one of [0]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Swap_file/Mount[swap]: Dependency Exec[Attach swap file] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Swap_file/Mount[swap]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.26 seconds
```

So basically, how do I setup a docker container to where I can run `swapon` without it erroring out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I asked in the `#docker` freenode room, and it turns out it's not actually possible to manage swap within a docker container:

```
10:44 AM <petems> cnf: How do I make it so that in a docker container for say, centos 6, I can run swap commands? Is that possible?
10:44 AM <cnf> petems: you can NOT swapon for _only_ the container, sorry
10:45 AM <cnf> petems: docker is NOT a VM
```

Answer (score 0):

To support swap in Docker you first have to enable cgroup management of memory and wap with these arguments: cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1.

If you're using grub it should be in /etc/default/grub and the line to add it to should be either GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX or GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. After making this change run sudo update-grub and reboot. A little more detail is here:
http://docker.readthedocs.org/en/v0.7.3/installation/kernel/

Let me know if this doesn't help and we can go further. If this doesn't help you then attempt to run those commands manually by launching the container in a shell. Run this to get an interactive shell and run the commands:
docker run -t -i image_name /bin/bash

Comment: Ok, neat! Good start... 

Would this be saved in a docker image if I have it in the Dockerfile? The testing process spins up a new docker image for each suite of tests. Can I save enabling the swap to the container?

Comment: Ah, does the cgroup_enable need to be run on the host itself? I'm running boot2docker on a Mac, so do I need to run that command on my machine or in the docker container?

Comment: It would have to be on the host, but great question on the boot2docker on Mac. I'm actually using that myself, but I'm not sure how to enable swap on it. I will have to poke at it a little.

Comment: According to those in the #docker IRC room, it's not possible :(

Comment: Do the abilities being added in docker 1.3 (i.e. shared images on mac host) help? http://blog.docker.com/2014/10/docker-1-3-signed-images-process-injection-security-options-mac-shared-directories/

Comment: Unfortunately not, the issue is being able to manipulate a swapfile from within the container, which apparently is impossible in Docker :(